# Selenium element location in Safari 12

Tags: c#, selenium, safari, browserstack

I'm using BrowserStack to run Selenium tests on a range of devices/browsers, including Safari 11, and it works fine. I'm now trying to add Safari 12 to the tests but I'm having trouble right from the start since I'm getting:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'
```

as soon as I try to get location on the first element. The following will fail when it reaches Location which is a `System.Drawing.Point`.

```
IWebElement element = this.Driver.FindElement(byLocator);
int x = element.Location.X;
```

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Not a workaround, but: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6637

Answer (score 1):

```
        /* Safari Hack */
        int x;
        int y;
        try
        {
            x = element.Location.X;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            x = ((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)element).LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView.X;
        }
        try
        {
            y = element.Location.Y;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            y = ((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)element).LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView.Y;
        }
```